# Send single SignalR message to members of multiple groups

Tags: c#, signalr

When the following SignalR code is run, a member who belongs to multiple qualifying groups will receive multiple messages:

```
public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    public void Send(string name, string message, params string[] groups)
    {
        this.Clients.Groups(groups).broadcast(name, message);
    }
}
```

Is there any way to send a **single** message to users who are members of any of the groups? In other words, if the `groups` parameter above is defined as `["grpA","grpB"]`, I would want the following to happen:

- User 1, member of grpA: 1 message
- User 2, member of grpB: 1 message
- User 3, member of grpA and grpB: **1 message**
- User 4, member of grpA and grpC: 1 message
- User 5, member of grpC: 0 messages

Answer (score 3):

There's not way to do this other than creating your own way to track users in each group and distinct users on your own before/on broadcasting.

Probably, this API will be introduced in the future releases, but for now there's not way to do that.

Answer (score 1):

No there isn't such feature as of now in signalR. To achieve this functionality you can store the connections somewhere in memory of database that contains the information about

MemberID, GroupID, SignalRConnectionID

and then get the distinct connectionIDs for members of specific groups and sent them a message using the syntax like

```
List<String> connectionIDs = #GET DISTINCT LIST OF CONNECTIONS FROM DB OR IN MEMORY STORAGE#;

Clients.Clients(connectionIDs).broadcast(name, message);
```